# Apache 2 won't serve index.php

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php

My test server will happily serve PHP pages if I navigate to them.

However, on one vhost, I have an index.php. This page will be served if I type in the URL. But, if I just type in 'http://mysite/', then the index.php will not be served.

I am running Apache 2.2 with the PHP module on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to set the DirectoryIndex directive in your apache config.

Something like

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
```

It can appear in either your server config, virtual host, directory, or an .htaccess file.

For full info:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html

Comment: Thanks Andrew. That did the trick.
I placed that line near the top of the config file for my virtual host, and then restarted apache.
Now the index.php page is visible straight away.